# How to add custom post type in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and want to add my custom post in woocommerce, so that my custom post type work like woocommerce post type "product" basically i need checkout of my post type through wordpress, my custom post type have price. i want that it will work same as product

Please help if anyone knows solution

Comment: there is a nice tutorial on it here : http://reigelgallarde.me/programming/how-to-add-custom-post-type-to-woocommerce/

Comment: I have already checked it but nothing happens
please explain if you have tried this

Comment: I have added this code in functions.php

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','reigel_woocommerce_get_price',20,2);
function reigel_woocommerce_get_price($price,$post){
 if ($post->post->post_type === 'opalhotel_room')
  $price = get_post_meta($post->id, "_base_price", true);
 return $price; 
}
after that i have tried this step
http://localhost/wordpress/cart/?add-to-cart=1.
according to my site url,

but nothing show like image